# Regex in Grafana

Tags: grafana

I want to write a regex in the variables page for a query. The regex should - exclude all values starting with "$.artemis" OR Values starting with "notif."

Comment: Also can someone suggest me a regex tool, where I can visualize the patterns with a given set of test data

Comment: The [Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) has a number of links to beginner resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `(?!\$\.artemis|notif\.)(.+)`. We use a *negative lookahead assertion* with `(?!...)` to make sure we do not match anything starting with `notif.` or `$.artemis`. Example:

```py
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(r"(?!\$\.artemis|notif\.)(.+)")
>>> pattern.match("hello") # Match
<re.Match object; span=(0, 5), match='hello'>
>>> pattern.match("$hello") # Match
<re.Match object; span=(0, 6), match='$hello'>
>>> pattern.match("$.artemis") # No match
>>> pattern.match("$.artemiswithsomething") # No match
>>> pattern.match("notif.") # No match
>>> pattern.match("notif.a") # No match
>>> pattern.match("notifwithoutfullstop") # Match
<re.Match object; span=(0, 20), match='notifwithoutfullstop'>
```